# Last part of proof in induction step

Tags: polynomials, induction, roots

I have done most of the following problem, but I am stuck in the last part:

for some polynomial $x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_0$ I have to find $r_1^2+r_2^2+...+r_n^2$ in terms of the coefficients $a_i$, where $r_i$ is the ith root. I got the solution $\sum r_i^2 = a_{n-1}^2 -2a_{n-2}$. I am sure it is correct, but I cannot prove it. I am trying to use induction and I am stuck at the inductive case $n+1$.
What I have is 
$r_1^2+...+r_{n+1}^2 = a_{n-1}^2-2a_{n-2} + r_{n+1}^2 \stackrel{?}{=} a_{n}^2-2a_{n-1}$

I don't know how to proceed from here. Any ideas? Thank you :)

Comment: Do you mean $r_i$ is the roots of the polynomial?

Comment: Yes! I am going to edit that. Sorry!

Comment: I think you're moving to the $a_k$ too soon. Why not just prove $$\sum r_j^2=(\sum r_j)^2 -2\sum_{i\not=j} r_i r_j ?$$

Comment: Unless you *have* to do it by induction, why not use [Vieta's relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta's_formulas) directly.

Comment: I would have to prove Vieta's relations as well. I am using induction because that's "what we know" as of today in the class.

Comment: It seems to me you need to do two things. Prove the base case and induction step. You seem to focus on the induction step. Here we needn't worry about induction at all. Only set out to prove from (**given**)$r_i^2+r_{i-1}^2+...+r_0^2=a_{n-1}^2-2a_{n-2}$ for any polynomial of degree $i$, $x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_{0}x^0$ it follows (**then**)that it is true for polynomial of degree $i+1$.

Comment: Then you need to prove the base case. Simply pick a degree $i$, it could be one or two or what ever you choose. You need to show for example say $i=1$ that for every possible polynomial of degree $1$, the sum of the roots of that polynomial (with leading coefficient 1 of course) is the difference of the coefficients ($2a_{n-2}=0$ in this case). Then this proves everything.

Comment: As I explained, I am just missing the induction step. But I already finished it. Thank you, though!

Answer (score 0):

Well, the easiest way is the using of Vieta's relations. But, your induction is not true. Let say the polynomial of degree $n+1$ with $n+1$ roots. We have

$$x^{n+1} + a_{n}x^{n} + \dots a_0 = \prod_{i=1}^{n+1}(x-r_i).$$

So, if you take n-roots $r_i$, where $i$ goes from 1 to n. Then, 
$$x^{n+1} + a_{n}x^{n} + \dots a_0 = P(x)(x-r_{n+1}),$$ where

$$P(x) = x^{n} + b_{n-1}x^{n} + \dots b_0$$ and by induction, you have $$\sum_{i=1}^n r_i^2 = b_{n-1}^2 - 2b_{n-2}.$$ So, you must check relation of $r_{n+1}$,$a_{n}$, $a_{n-1}$ and $b_{n-1}$, $b_{n-2}$. Hope it helps.

EDIT: Let me clarify. We assume that

$$r_1^2 + \dots r_n^2 = a_{n-1}^2 - a_{n-2},$$ for the polynomial of degree n.

We must prove that with the polynomial of degree $n+1$ which has $n+1$ roots, then $$r_1^2 + \dots r_{n+1}^2 = a_n^2 - 2a_{n-1}.$$ And you cannot apply like you wrote $r_1^2 + \dots r_{n+1}^2 = a_{n-1}^2 - 2a_{n-2} + r_{n+1}^2$.

Comment: Why is my induction not true?

Comment: You assume that $r_1^2  + \dots r_n^2= a_{n-1}^2 - 2a_{n-2}$ for the case of polynomial of degree $n+1$. It is not true.

Comment: I know, I did not assume that. I assumed that $r_1^2 + ... r_{n+1}^2 = a_n^2-2a_{n-1}$ but since "I am not sure about it" because that is what I have to prove I used $\stackrel{?}{=}$

Comment: Why not? We know by our induction assumption that $r_1^2 + ... r_n^2 = a_{n-1}^2 - 2a_{n-2}$, so we have that $(r_1^2 + ... r_n^2) + r_{n+1}^2 = (a_{n-1}^2 - 2a_{n-2}) + r_{n+1}^2$. We are just adding $+r_{n+1}^2$ to both sides of the equation.

Comment: `Why not?` Because when you add the root $r_{n+1}$ the degree and the coefficients of the polynomial both change. The induction hypothesis is about the sum of the $n$ roots of an $n^{th}$ degree polynomial. You cannot assume that it holds true for a subset of $n$ out $n+1$ roots of an $(n+1)^{th}$ degree polynomial, and in fact it doesn't. Try a simple case, for example $n=2\,$, to convince yourself.